# h2o flow versus python shell

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

I have build a model in h2o flow.  Once completed I save the file to my local machine.  Next, I import some new data via Flow and python shell, I then load the model and run predict on the dataframe.

I should get the exact same results as the dataframe and model are both the same.  Just different environments.  However, I get a different predictions in the different environments.  Anybody have a similar experience?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem (I will delete my answer). Can you give more information, e.g. which ML algorithm, what kind of prediction (regression, binomial, multinomial) and how different are the predictions that each client API is giving?

Comment: Thanks --  GBM, Binomial.  On a dataset of 9K, flow returns 1.5k positive predictions and python returns 3k positive predictions.

Comment: That is a big difference. Are you able to make a Minimal Reproducible example? As it smells like a bug, I'd post it on the JIRA (https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV/summary ). The only other thing I can think is that you have data rounding... but IIUC you've loaded the data frame in to H2O (with either Flow or Python), loaded the model (with either Flow or Python), and then are using the same frame and model from both clients.